# xml2csv with xml Attribute and Values in Python

Tags: python, xml, csv, parsing, converters

How can i convert i large xml (500M)with complex structure in to csv ?

Sample XML:

```
<images>
<image ismain="1" sml="1" med="1" big="0"><id>2</id><title><![CDATA[]]></title><url>www.mysite.com/45656.jpeg</url></image>
<image ismain="1" sml="1" med="0" big="1"><id>2</id><title><![CDATA[]]></title><url>www.mysite.com/354456.jpeg</url></image>
</images>
```

Code Python :

```
from xmlutils.xml2csv import xml2csv
converter = xml2csv("/home/mehul/Downloads/instant/static/images.xml", "/home/mehul/Downloads/instant/static/images.csv", encoding="utf-8")
converter.convert(tag="image")
```

Actual Output:

```
id,title,url
2,,www.mysite.com/45656.jpeg
2,,www.mysite.com/354456.jpeg
```

Expected Output:

```
id,ismain sml med big,title,url
2,,,,,www.mysite.com/45656.jpeg
2,,,,,www.mysite.com/354456.jpeg
```

Comment: your expected output `id,ismain sml med big,title,url` shows an arbitrary processing logic: you are mixing tags and attributes. Simple and explicit conversion via `converter.convert(tag="image")` won't help you

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest for your valuable input .

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have used `xmlutils`, it doesn't work well with complex structures, such as XML with nested tags. Furthermore, you want all the attributes too.

I had worked on this in a company project, and basically I had to write my own parsing code.

You can use Python's built-in [xml](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) library to parse through the XML, and check for events such as `start` and `end` tags, and then extract the data.

In fact, if all your tag names are in `lowercase`, you can just use Python's [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html). It has pre-defined functions for handling events which you can just override. It however converts tag names to lowercase (if they are in uppercase originally).